# The FRW universe is NOT asymptotically flat? Its mass?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, cosmology, mass, hamiltonian-formalism

The Friedman-Robertson-Walker (FRW) metric in the comoving coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\varphi)$ which describes  a homogeneous and
isotropic universe is
$$
ds^2\,= -dt^2+\frac{a(t)^2}{1-kr^2}\,dr^2 + a(t)^2 r^2\,\Big( d\theta^2+\sin^2 \!\theta \,d\varphi^2 \Big)
$$
where  $k$ is the curvature normalized into $\{-1\,,0\,,+1\}$ which refers to a closed, flat and open universe, respectively; and $a(t)$ is the scale factor.

My question is, this FRW metric is NOT asymptotically flat at spatial infinity $r\to+\infty$, isn't it? Thus, we can not calculate the so-called ADM mass (Arnowitt-Deser-Misner), right? If so, how to get **the mass of the matter content** from the metric?

Note: I do not mean the trivial $m=\rho V$, I mean the mass obtained from the FRW metric.

The matter/material content determines geometry/metric, and reversely the metric reflects the matter content. So I'm trying to recover the material mass (not including the gravitational energy) from the FRW metric.

Comment: Why do you think there is a well defined mass?

Comment: @MBN Thank you, MBN. Yes. I mean the mass of the matter content, not that of the gravitational field.

Comment: Oh, I read your question again and had to delete my answer since it gave only the $\rho V$ answer. I think there is no good definition of what you would like. It would probably be possible only for one type of source, i.e. for radiation a larger universe would be more energetic, but for dark energy it would be less energetic. Etc.

Comment: @David I tried to think about the whole thing a bit more and decided to rewrite and undelete the answer. It is now as close to a complete answer as I could get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is what do we need the matter content of the universe for. As I understand it, in the usual case we want to find the conserved quantity associated with a certain conserved current gained by the projection of the energy-momentum tensor into a Killing vector, as for example in the [paper by Abott and Deser](http://neurotheory.columbia.edu/~larry/AbbottNP82a.pdf).

The requirement of asymptotical behaviour seems to be connected only with the elimination of boundary terms, i.e. of the flux of the spatial part of the 4-vector current "through infinity". The integration of the divergence of the four-vector over the whole space-slice then gives us a time conservation of the space-slice sum of the zeroth component of the 4-vector.

In the FLRW models, there is however no time-like Killing vector and thus no kind of conserved Killing energy or matter content. The only possibility of a preferred time-like vector is through the orthogonal vector to all the three space-like Killing vectors. This is the four-vector used for the definition of matter density $\rho$ and the trivial (using Einstein equations) 
$$m=\rho V = \int \frac{3}{8 \pi} \frac{\dot{a}^2 + k}{a^2} dV_{sp} \,.$$
Where $dV_{sp}$ is just the spatial part of the volume element.

But by definition, there cannot be a purely matter-based conserved energy and thus and ADM-sense matter content. I also believe that the main problem with this kind of generalization is also the fact that the ADM mass is designed to portray the energy content of an "isolated" space-time or at least a space-time with a certain dominating background. A cosmological situation defines such a dominant background and thus the notion of ADM mass should not be expected to hold up.

Comment: Great! Thank you very very very much for the detailed explaination! It is very helpful for me.